# Most efficient way to swap two array values in Perl

Tags: perl

I was curious what the most efficient way to swap two elements in an array in Perl would be.

Say I want to switch the elements with indexes of 3 and 5 respectively, what would be the fastest way to do that?

My thoughts were something like:

```
@array[3,5] = @array[5,3];
```

Is this very efficient? My hope is that it wouldn't make a difference if those two array values contained large amounts of data. I would expect the back-end to change the pointers around, without doing any actual copying. Is that correct?

Comment: If you're worried about large data, store references in the array instead. Then you're moving two small things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean "large amounts of data"? If you mean references to large data structures, it doesn't matter how you do it; it will be crazy fast. (Less than one nanosecond per swap.) So I'm going to assume you meant "large strings".

---

Before 5.20, the code you posted would copy the strings. You can avoid that using [Data::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Alias).

```
use Data::Alias;
alias @array[3,5] = @array[5,3];
```

Or you can do the same with a little XS if you want to avoid the syntax magic of Data::Alias:

```
void swap_array_elements(AV * av, IV ix1, IV ix2) {
   SV ** p_ele1 = av_fetch(av, ix1, 1);
   SV ** p_ele2 = av_fetch(av, ix2, 1);
   SV * sv = *p_ele1;
   *p_ele1 = *p_ele2;
   *p_ele2 = sv;
}
```

---

Since 5.20, the string copies were replaced with a simple pointer swap.

```
$ 5.18t/bin/perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   my @a = qw( a b c d e f );
   Dump($a[3]);
   Dump($a[5]);
   @a[3,5] = @a[5,3];
   Dump($a[3]);
   Dump($a[5]);
' 2>&1 | grep '^  PV'
  PV = 0x353fba0 "d"\0
  PV = 0x357abb0 "f"\0
  PV = 0x3541ff0 "f"\0
  PV = 0x3537940 "d"\0

$ 5.20t/bin/perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   my @a = qw( a b c d e f );
   Dump($a[3]);
   Dump($a[5]);
   @a[3,5] = @a[5,3];
   Dump($a[3]);
   Dump($a[5]);
' 2>&1 | grep '^  PV'
  PV = 0xe9ace0 "d"\0
  PV = 0xe8f230 "f"\0
  PV = 0xe8f230 "f"\0
  PV = 0xe9ace0 "d"\0
```

This means that the straightforward `@array[3,5] = @array[5,3];` will do just fine.

Comment: (That code can be run by Inline::C with no modification, by the way.)

Comment: (This will work even if the array elements didn't previously exist.)

Answer (score 4):

Running bvr's benchmark script with a modification:

```
my @array = ('thing' x 1E5, 'stuff' x 5E5, 'that' x 1E6, 'joe' x 5E6,
             'sofa' x 1E7, 'jim' x 5E7);
```

Results:

```
           Rate      slice       temp      alias
slice    1.98/s         --       -69%      -100%
temp     6.47/s       227%         --      -100%
alias 4218715/s 213045016%  65227727%         --
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess was that simple swapping via temp variable would be faster than slicing. Benchmarking

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
use Data::Alias;

my @array = ('thing', 'stuff', 'that', 'joe', 'sofa', 'jim');
cmpthese(-2, {
    slice => sub {
        @array[3,5] = @array[5,3];
    },
    temp  => sub {
        my $tmp = $array[3];
        $array[3] = $array[5];
        $array[5] = $tmp;
    },
    alias => sub {
        alias @array[3,5] = @array[5,3];
    }
});
```

seems to confirm that:

```
           Rate slice alias  temp
slice  940155/s    --  -70%  -73%
alias 3151934/s  235%    --   -9%
temp  3472932/s  269%   10%    --
```

**Edit:** After I've seen ikegami's comment, changed to strings and also added `alias`. Still looks like temp variable is fastest.

Comment: This is over-optimization. You should do whatever reads best, which is the slice.

Comment: The OP specifically said the values contains "large amounts of data", so your benchmark is worthless for that data set.

Comment: For the input you did use, you drew the wrong conclusion. The conclusion should have been: "Even the slowest takes just 1 nanosecond, so there is no speed problem there."

Comment: @ikegami - the example just show option how OP can arrange test and see how it behaves in her conditions. Benchmarking itself is almost always microoptimization, it is usually better to profile real program.

Comment: Benchmarks aren't just for microoptimisations. I used Benchmark to evaluate different XML parsers, for example. Similarly, if you had used appropriate data, Benchmarking would have been useful here too.

Comment: Add: `elemlist => sub { ( $array[3], $array[5] ) = ( $array[5], $array[3] ) }` and you will see that an explicit list of two elements is faster than a slice (though not as fast as avoiding list assignment altogether as temp does).

Answer (score 0):

For particular case to swap first and last value you may use:

```
push @l, shift @l;
```

The Benchmark results:

```
cmpthese( 10000000, {
    tmp  => sub{
        my @l =  ( 1, 2 );
        my $tmp = $l[0];
        $l[0] =  $l[1];
        $l[1] =  $tmp;
    },
    shift  => sub{ #
        my @l =  ( 1, 2 );
        push @l, shift @l;
    },
    slice  => sub{
        my @l =  ( 1, 2 );
        @l[0,1] =  @l[1,0];
    },
});

           Rate slice   tmp shift
slice 2544529/s    --   -4%  -38%
tmp   2645503/s    4%    --  -36%
shift 4115226/s   62%   56%    --
```